# Multiple strings in one SQL field

Tags: sql, string, json

I am trying to revamp an order system for an e-commerce web site. The header table for the orders is `tbl_orders`, that's working fine but there is another table underneath that (so to speak) called `tbl_orderitems`

In this table `tbl_orderitems` I store an Id that refers to the items image but sometimes there is more than one image associated with an item so i'm now thinking of ways to store more than one filename in one field.

So let's say the field is called *Filename*, this might be a `varchar(400)` for e.g. I would want to store more than one filename like

> Images/cards/sides/complete/145.jpg,
>   Images/cards/sides/complete/146.jpg,
>   Images/cards/sides/complete/147.jpg

So, my first idea is to save it as comma delimited, but what I'm asking is - is there a better way to do this? As in, a faster way? I will be using ASP.NET C# to read this data out and will need to iterate through the strings. I have recently been using JSON, is it worth using this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a separate table with two columns that associates order-item ids with filenames.

If it's possible for order-items to share files, then I'd suggest you also create an "images" table that stores image-id and filename (and whatever other attributes you want to associate with an image), and replace the filename column in the first table I mentioned with the image-id.

Comment: That was a simple one. Just had a discussion and we have come to the conclusion that this is the best way to go about solving this problem. I think it gives us more flexibility, we can query it easily and also store more data with it, size etc..

Comment: There is more than one table for images so we cant store an id. we have image tables for business cards, calendars, photo prints so obviously we cant refer the id back to the tables. This is why we are just storing the filenames.

Comment: "more than one table for images" sets off alarm bells in my head. Is it necessary to split image information across multiple tables? One alternative is to have a single table that holds image information, and then separate tables that simply store image ids for the different categories (and any category-specific attributes).

Comment: No no, we have seperate 'systems'. So we have systems that deal with seperate things for instance we have business cards and photo prints. There's more to it than that but the way we need to do it is to just refer to the filename. I went down the route of having categories before but it went t*ts up. I had one table for all systems it just didn't work. We have more flexibility with the way were doing it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two tables instead of one.

like following:

```
create table tbl_orderitemsgroup (
id int identity(1,1) not null )

create table tbl_orderitem (
id int identity(1,1) not null,
group_id int not null
)
```

with foreign key tbl_orderitem.group_id to tbl_orderitemgroup.id